How do I sort by lowest score?
I can sort questions and filter by the highest score but not by the lowest score. How do I view the lowest scored questions of all time?
And how do I view the oldest of all questions, for example, when I click on the "last page" it is unable to load, as if it deleted everything after a certain date, why is the page number still there then? Hmm?

Normal way
You choose your sorting order, then navigate to the last page.
This is the only regular way to "reverse" the sort order that is built into the sites
Hacky way
It is possible to force the sites to unlisted sort orders. You can figure out the "hack" yourself - choose a sort order from the dropdown and look at the URL that you get redirected to. For example, if you choose "Date created (oldest first)" in the URL you would find the query parameter ?answertab=createdasc or in other words "sort by 'created' in 'ascending' order". While choosing "Highest score (default)" uses ?answertab=scoredesc or "sort by 'score' in 'descending' order".
Therefore, you can manually force the sorting to obey unlisted orders by adding ?answertab=<desired order> parameter to a URL with an appropriate value. Here is a full list of sort parameters that I know of (regular ones and inverted):



sorting parameter value
sorting
in dropdown?




createdasc
by creation date, ascending
yes


createddesc
by creation date, descending
no


modifieddesc
by modification date, descending
yes


modifiedasc
by modification date, ascending
no


scoredesc
by score, descending
yes


scoreasc
by score, ascending
no


trending
trending sort
only on Stack Overflow



Note 1: sorting is sticky
Answer sorting will persist for any further page loads. Once the sort order is set via the query parameter, next time you visit a page the parameter will not be there but the last value you had will be used. If you applied an unlisted sort order, the dropdown it will just show the default "Highest score".
This will not really cause any real problems, however, it may not be obvious what you have chosen. I have end up confused a few times by this. But you can always just reset the sort order via the dropdown.
Per site
Also, for clarity - the answer sorting persists per site. It can be different in different places. Including main and meta sites.
Note 2: no guarantee the unlisted options will work forever
Since these are unlisted, there is no guarantee a future change will not deprecate them. However, they work for now and have worked for a while. Just a warning that it cannot be taken for granted they would continue.
